# Erro "could not be parsed" ao converter string para tipo DateTime

Tags: java, datetime

Recebo uma String de DataHora assim:

> 2017-10-11 10:39:04.217923

Retiro esse número após o ponto, e utilizo o `LocalDateTime.parse()`:

```
private final String PATTERN_DATA_HORA = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

[...]

 Movimentacao movimentacao = new Movimentacao();
 StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(movimentos.getJSONObject(i).get("dt_andamento_pa").toString());
 movimentacao.setData(LocalDateTime.parse(stringTokenizer.nextToken("."), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PATTERN_DATA_HORA)).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

Tenho o seguinte erro no parse:

> Text `2017-10-11 10:39:04` could not be parsed at index 2.

Obs.: Já vi em fóruns gringos situações parecidas, mas o erro continua. O que fazer?

Comment: Esse **.217923** são os milisegundos, é um tipo de dado feito para ter precisão em nanosegundos. E se você der um parse em toda string o que acontece, sem tirar os milisegundos no caso?

Comment: Dá o mesmo erro: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-10-11 10:39:04.217923' could not be parsed at index 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porque seu pattern não reflete o formato data recebido. Você diz que a string que será convertida (parse) tem o formato `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` quando em realidade o formato é `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Nós colocamos o formato de saída quando já temos um LocalDateTime e queremos que ele seja exibido de forma diferente, veja:

```
LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatador = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
hoje.format(formatador); // 11/08/2017
```

No seu caso você quer converter uma string em um LocalDateTime.

**Atenção!** Ao colocar `LocalDateTime.parse(string,formatter).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);` você deixa de ter como retorno um LocalDateTime e passa a ter um OffsetDateTime.

https://ideone.com/24ACmb